# MVC Attribute, Validate Field based on the values of at least 2 other fileds

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, field, foolproof-validation

Good day,

I am using MVC4 and Foolproof validation.

I am trying to validate a field based on the values of at least 2 other fields.

```
public int pos1 { get; set; }
public int pos2 { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("pos1",1,ErrorMessage="some error message" )]
public int? IrdKsOption { get; set; }
```

RequireIf can on be specified once.
RequireIf only takes 1 fieldname and value.

How would i go about doing something like this

```
public int pos1 { get; set; }
public int pos2 { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("pos1,pos2",[1,5],ErrorMessage="some error message" )]
public int? IrdKsOption { get; set; }
```

so that if pos1=1 and pos2=5 validation should fail

Comment: You will need to write you own validation attribute that implements `IClientValidatable` - refer [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) to get you started

Comment: thank you, this seems to have helped my issue